# Ubuntu 12.04 stuck at logo with 5 dots on Macbook Pro

Tags: 12.04, mac, logo

I have an old Macbook Pro 4,1, which I had loaded with 12.04 when it was released. Yesterday I took out the laptop and applied some 480mb of updates and rebooted. Since then it is stuck at the Ubuntu logo with 5 dots. I've waited for about half n hour but it doesn't proceed.

I've tried hitting 'e' key during booting but it doesn't get me into edit mode. From online forums and blogs, this seems like a graphic driver issue (nvidia-current) but I'm not sure how to get to console or boot menu to do something.

Here's what happens -

- A light blue screen (Mac boot screen) appears when I power on MBP
- Only Ubuntu is installed on the laptop, so it directly tries to boot Ubuntu
- I get a blank screen with an underscore flashing on top-left corner of the screen
- Then I get a blank purple screen for about 5-6 seconds before getting the Ubuntu logo with 5 dots
- It gets stuck on the logo screen forever

How do I proceed on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Choose nomodeset in grub before proceeding to boot.  From memory, it's on the menu under the F6 key (look at the bottom right of the grub menu screen.

If the grub boot menu isn't showing before you see the logo and 5 dots, try holding the 'shift' key while it starts.

Comment: I don't get any grub menu during boot. Holding 'shift' during boot didn't help, I still got the logo with 5 dots.

Comment: Hmmm. Others have had this problem too.  Lots of info if you google "show grub during boot".  For example see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1520821

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this by uninstalling *unity* and installing *gdm*

*sudo apt-get update*

*sudo apt-get remove unity*

*sudo apt-get install gdm*

It works in ubuntu 12.04